# when using intellij running dual monitors on ubuntu, how to get menu to get menu popup not to drift back to first window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use idea on ubuntu linux w/ 2 monitors.  I often pull up 2 projects so I can copy stuff from one to the other, and I have one project in a window on 
one monitor screen, and the other on the second screen.

My problem is this:   when I open the second project in the 'non-primary' monitor screen, and i click on an item in the top level menu bar 
the menu pop up displays on the primary monitor screen...not the secondary one...    it does not matter if I have the project in the secondary 
monitor window maximized or not...        the pop up just drifts over to the primary monitor screen..

it is not a fatal error.. I can move my mouse over to the first monitor window and click on the sub menu i want..

but it is so  annoying. I'm wondering if this is a bug, or perhaps there is a work around for it ?

Also posted on IntelliJ user community board. If they answer, I will post the response here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is unfortunately a Ubuntu specific bug. I recommend you vote for and track it: [Pop-up dialogs are sometimes misplaced on Ubuntu 12.04 with dual screens](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106048)

Comment: OK.. i upvoted.  looks like i'm the only one who voted ?    maybe i'll have to go door to door on this one. ;^)     anyway.. thanks for confirming that it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest 2 workaround solutions for this issue.

**Workaround 1**
I use Intellij on my right hand side monitor. But the menus are displayed on left hand side monitor. So, I opened "Displays" configuration and moved the right hand side monitor to the left. Now, the menus are displayed on the correct monitor. Note that, the monitor is still stays on my right hand side:).

**Workaroud 2:**
Downgrade to JDK 1.6.

Comment: Workaround 1 worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3 on JDK 1.7. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, you this worked for me (under xfce it's enough to set the desired display to "primary")